# strtotime() should return 0 if the argument is also 0

Tags: php, date, strtotime

How can I get the function `strtotime()` to return 0 if the argument is also 0?

In my example, $testvar2 returns "empty".

```
$testvar = 0;
$testvar2 = strtotime($testvar);

print_r($testvar2);
```

Comment: Have you tried something and why do you need this?

Comment: You cannot make functions do stuff that they were not designed to do.

Comment: If the variable is `0`, and you need a `0`... just use the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply make a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), since [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) will return false if it fails you can simply return 0 otherwise it will return the correct value.

```
$testvar2 = strtotime($testvar)?:0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Its not returning empty its returning you `bool(false)`. Check with [var_dump](http://codepad.org/h3FhVKkH) instead of print_r.

*Workaround:*

```
$testvar2 = ($testvar) ? strtotime($testvar) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a check for that variable(0, false, null, not set etc.). Try with -

```
$testvar2= (!empty($testvar)) ? strtotime($testvar) : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTime($testvar){
    return ($testvar == 0)? 0 : strtotime($testvar);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static function myStrToTime($var=null)
{
    if($var)
        return strtotime($var);
    return 0;
}
```

No offense, but maybe you should look up some more tutorials on PHP. :)

Comment: for me this is overkill

Comment: How is this overkill?

Comment: Why so complications?

Comment: Please, be more specific. What is complicated about this?

Comment: Why do you need the function?

Comment: You don't need the function, it's just for readability. You could of course take the code out of the function and use it that way. I really don't see the complication in my answer.

Comment: @sgtBOSE i'm pretty sure he will say for code reusability

Comment: Is there any need of that?